# Get the / separated params from a url in nextJs

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I have the following url:

profile/myname

In my express.js config I do the following to forward to my page profile.js:

```
server.get('/profile/:username', (req, res) => {
        const actualPage = '/profile';
        return app.render(req, res, actualPage);
    });
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

How do I then get the :username in my profile.js? somewhere in the getInitialProps I assume, but how exactly?

Comment: The `:username` should be available in `req.params`.

Answer (score 0):

The `:username` of your route will be available in `req.params`. You can read more about this and other methods of express [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params) in the official documentation.